# Why I have to sudo a command from daemon process?

Tags: linux, bash, erlang, daemon, sudo

I have a problem about `sudo`.

I call an Erlang script *from a daemon process*. (This daemon process is defined by xinetd, and this process will execute an bash script in it. I wrote my Erlang script command into the bash script). The Erlang script is like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env escript
main(_) ->
    ok.
```

The script is quite simple and it is ok when I execute it under the shell command line.

But when I call it from the *daemon process*, it failed with return code of non-zero. I really have no idea.

When I try `sudo /path/to/my/erlang_script`, it turns alright!!

I am the `root` myself. Why I have to add `sudo`?

My xinetd conf is like: (as you can see 'user' is setup to be 'root')

```
service gtpgwagent
{
        type            = UNLISTED
        flags           = REUSE
        disable         = no
        socket_type     = stream
        protocol        = tcp
        wait            = no
        user            = root
        instances       = UNLIMITED
        server          = /lab/subsysserv/sbin/in.gtpgwagent
        server_args     = gtpgw
        log_type        = FILE /tmp/ggsnagent_logfile
        log_on_success  += DURATION USERID HOST EXIT
        log_on_failure  += USERID HOST
        env             = /usr/bin:/bin
        port            = 1761
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "failed with return code of 0"? A process exit code of 0 [means success](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#POSIX) (it's the opposite of C).

Comment: @thatotherguy, sorry, typo... not zero

Answer (score 2):

*The daemon process* is neither running as root nor as a user that has permission to run that script (or, the most common case, is not allowed to do something that script does), so things don't work out.

*You* are running as root, so whatever you try always works (which is sort of scary, so be careful).

Change permissions on the script to accommodate whatever xinetd is setting the daemon process user to be, and make sure whatever you have the script do is something the daemon process user is allowed to do. Whatever you do, though, do *not* set a daemon to run as root -- that is just an accident (or crack) waiting to happen.

**Edit**

RHEL 6.x is almost guaranteed to prevent daemons running as root from doing *almost anything*.

- Try turning SELinux off and see if that changes the outcome (do `setenforce 0`, then run your test, then do `setenforce 1` to turn it back on).
- Set the user to something different (create a system user for this purpose if you need: `useradd -r [blahblah]`).
- Check how role-based permissions work (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rbac-selinux/).
- Look for threads related to this issue somewhere like [unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [serverfault.se](https://serverfault.com/) or a RHEL/SL/CentOS IRC channel or forum -- you're almost certainly not the only one who has run into this.
- **Whatever you do [don't disable SELinux because of this](http://stopdisablingselinux.com/)!** Seriously, [don't](http://sheltren.com/stop-disabling-selinux). As a developer or a sysop or as devops you should [learn how it works](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/) -- it is a very important tool. [Don't stoop to the pixels-first mindset.](http://zxq9.com/archives/535)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand "The daemon process is neither running as root nor as a user that has permission to run that script". Because I have setup the user to be root.

Comment: @ruanhao Then you likely have a different kind of permissions problem -- or a simple typo somewhere. What distro are you using? Most distros have a security permissions system (like AppArmor or SELinux or something else similar) that will prevent daemons running as root from being able to do much by default -- specifically because running a daemon as root is *bad*.

Comment: I am using 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.1'. I add `ps -p $$` in my script, and it shows that the user of current process is root.

Comment: @ruanhao Updated my answer. There isn't a simple one-off answer to this because I don't know everything about your system or the overall effect you are trying to achieve. I *do* know that running daemons as root is universally regarded as a Bad Thing and that nearly every system's security defaults are set to prevent root daemons from being able to do much (this aspect of your situation -- running a daemon as root -- is already a "Y" element to your XY problem).

Comment: Yes, your point is right. Thank you for your suggestion and patience!